# Different behavior of C# WPF DataGrid on different computers

Tags: visual-studio, c#, wpf

I have a problem troubleshooting what's wrong with software I've been working on.

This is my company's code so I can go into details (pasting code and so on).

Anyway - I have a piece of C# & WPF DataGrid. It's behaving strangely. On some computers it works fine, on others it works like that - you put some value into 1 or more cells and the same values shows few rows below. However it only on view side, because if you click on the cell real value appears. Also when scrolling cells are "loosing" real value.

I found similar questions, but it was stricly connected with the code. I don't think that my case is code related - it looks more like a environment related.

I compared two of my machines (on one it is working, on second it's not) and main difference is Visual Studio installed.

Do you have any idea how to determine what's the reason of that different behavior? What tools can I use? What to look for?

**EDIT:**

Environments are different (all 4 I know about):
 - 1 is a physical machine (Windows 10), 3 are Virtual Machines (Windows 7)

- On 2 of VM it works, on other 2 machines it does not
- (from here I'm talking only about my 2 machines, both VM)
- Both compilled (debug or release) and installed are working on one of my VM. Moving compilled version to other machine results in the same problem.
- Both machines has Visual Studio 2015 installed
- Targeted Net Framework is 4.6.2. Installed on both machines are

> ```
> Net Framework
> 4.5
> 4.5.1
> 4.6
> 4.6.1
> 4.6.2
> 4.7.2
> ```

Not working:

```
MVC++ Redistributables
2008 x64 9.0.30729.6161 
2008 x86 9.0.30729.4148 
2008 x86 9.0.30729.6161 
2010 x64 10.0.30319 
2010 x86 10.0.30319 
2012 x64/x86 11.0.60610 
2012 x86 11.0.61030 
2013 x64/x86 12.0.21005 
2015-2019 x64/x86 14.22.27821
```

Working:

```
MVC++ Redistributables
2005 8.0.56336
2008 x64 9.0.30729.6161 
2008 x86 9.0.30729.4148 
2008 x86 9.0.30729.6161 
2010 x64 10.0.30319 
2010 x86 10.0.30319 
2012 x64/x86 11.0.60610 
2012 x86 11.0.61030 
2013 x64/x86 12.0.21005 
2017 x68/x86 14.15.26706
```

- Code mixes C# and C++ with some external libraries.
- There is only one HotFix that is installed on the machine where it does work and not on the other: KB4507449. There are some additional installed on the machine where it doesn't work.
- Simple example with DataGrid works OK.

Edit:
Do you know any easy way to compare dll being used?

Comment: Please do not provide code.  Programming questions are out of scope here at Super User.  If you feel your question cannot get an answer without submitting code, the replicates the problem you are trying to solve, you should delete this question and simply submit your question to Stack Overflow.  However, if you stick to the environmental differences, you have to tell us about the environments.  Otherwise, we will be unable to answer your question, and in its current form anyone with significant knowledge about C# applications wouldn't be able to submit an answer (like myself).

Comment: I eddited my question. I hope it helps

Comment: "All machines have a lot of "Microsoft Visual C++ xxxx Redistributable"" - What versions specifically?  Does your application use it?  If your application does not then this factoid is not relevant.  What version of the .NET Framework do you have installed on each machine?  What version of the .NET Framework are you targeting?  What version of Visual Studio are you using?  What .NET Targettting Pack do you have installed?  Do not submit a comment, edit your question, and remove/add relevant details to your question. "I have VS installed' is unhelpful; "I have VS 2019 15.2 installed is helpful"

Comment: If you wrote it all yourself then you should write a simple example that is open source(to all), and doesn't have anything company specific and has the problem.

Comment: Maybe your issue is graphics card related? Why don't you try a little program with a datagrid view full of data and scroll it and see if you run into that

Comment: I didn't write it myself and I cannot provide even simple example which would mimic/show what that code does because of complexity of that solution. It's tone of code which in most part I still don't understand, pretty new to C#.

Comment: so you don't know how to write a program with a datagridview component  and fill the datagridview with -any- data?  if you can then do that, and see if it has the same issue (like with scrolling and losing their value) and the refresh only happening when clicking on the cell.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. As for graphic card - it cannot be an issue, because VM are the same as for hardware virtualization. One was done by cloning the other.

Comment: also, try building it making an EXE out of it and see if you get different behaviour.. then you know it's not different code.. but still, there may be a code solution like refreshing on scroll.

Comment: @matt - Does the application import any references from the Windows SDK, which would be more likely installed on the working VM, than the non-working VM due to Visual Studio being installed?  Are you able to clone one of the VMs that are not working, install Visual Studio 2019 Community on it, to determine if the application outside of Visual Studio (but still installed) works or not?

Comment: @Ramhound - I am pretty sure that .Net Framework is the problem here. In C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net there are assemblies. On two working computers some files are in version 4.7.3260.0. On the two other where it does not work version is 4.8.3761.0. Any idea how to investigate it further?

Comment: @barlop - as above.

Comment: @matt perhaps you could experiment with adding and removing specific versions of dot net framework?

Comment: @barlop - It seems that for everything lower than 4.8 is OK. Now I would like to know what I can do with that knowledge, but I suppose this question is more for stack overflow.

Comment: @matt - You shouldn't have assemblies with 4.8.3761 unless you had .NET Framework 4.8 installed.

Comment: @matt  perhaps SO, but you will have much better results from them if you can make a demo program. Now you know it's not a nitty gritty code glitch that you would have to reproduce.  You  could try to copy your program, and trace the program and understand the structure a bit.. comment out chunks. Put dummy data in.  Or just trace it enough that you have a good idea how they made the 'wpf datagrid'.. Figure out what you need in the program to reproduce the bug.  If you just made a program with that grid and filled it with data, does that set it off

Comment: @Ramhound - It looks that Win10 has these dll files in that version despite the fact that no .Net Framework 4.8 is installed.

Comment: @matt - If you have Windows 10 version 1903 installed then .NET Framework 4.8 is already installed.  If you are not running Windows 10 version 1903, then you have to specifically install .NET Framework 4.8, for the system to have .NET Framework 4.8 assemblies.